# Sorting and paging using Angularjs and MVC4

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I am working in MVC4 with angularjs.I wanted to perform paging and sorting .
below is sample code

```
**Angularjs part**
=======
    function ctrlRead($scope, $filter) {
        // init
        $scope.sortingOrder = sortingOrder;
        $scope.reverse = false;
        $scope.filteredItems = [];
        $scope.groupedItems = [];
        $scope.itemsPerPage = 5;
        $scope.pagedItems = [];
        $scope.currentPage = 0;
        $scope.items = [
            {"id":"1","name":"name 1","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 1","field4":"field4 1","field5 ":"field5 1"}, 
            {"id":"2","name":"name 2","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 2","field4":"field4 2","field5 ":"field5 2"}, 
            {"id":"3","name":"name 3","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 3","field4":"field4 3","field5 ":"field5 3"}, 
            {"id":"4","name":"name 4","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 4","field4":"field4 4","field5 ":"field5 4"}, 
            {"id":"5","name":"name 5","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 5","field4":"field4 5","field5 ":"field5 5"}, 
            {"id":"6","name":"name 6","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 6","field4":"field4 6","field5 ":"field5 6"}, 
            {"id":"7","name":"name 7","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 7","field4":"field4 7","field5 ":"field5 7"}, 
            {"id":"8","name":"name 8","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 8","field4":"field4 8","field5 ":"field5 8"}, 
            {"id":"9","name":"name 9","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 9","field4":"field4 9","field5 ":"field5 9"}, 
            {"id":"10","name":"name 10","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 10","field4":"field4 10","field5 ":"field5 10"}, 
            {"id":"11","name":"name 11","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 11","field4":"field4 11","field5 ":"field5 11"}, 
            {"id":"12","name":"name 12","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 12","field4":"field4 12","field5 ":"field5 12"}, 
            {"id":"13","name":"name 13","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 13","field4":"field4 13","field5 ":"field5 13"}, 
            {"id":"14","name":"name 14","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 14","field4":"field4 14","field5 ":"field5 14"}, 
            {"id":"15","name":"name 15","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 15","field4":"field4 15","field5 ":"field5 15"}, 
            {"id":"16","name":"name 16","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 16","field4":"field4 16","field5 ":"field5 16"}, 
            {"id":"17","name":"name 17","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 17","field4":"field4 17","field5 ":"field5 17"}, 
            {"id":"18","name":"name 18","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 18","field4":"field4 18","field5 ":"field5 18"}, 
            {"id":"19","name":"name 19","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 19","field4":"field4 19","field5 ":"field5 19"}, 
            {"id":"20","name":"name 20","description":"description 1","field3":"field3 20","field4":"field4 20","field5 ":"field5 20"}
        ];

        var searchMatch = function (haystack, needle) {
            if (!needle) {
                return true;
            }
            return haystack.toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        };

        // init the filtered items
        $scope.search = function () {
            $scope.filteredItems = $filter('filter')($scope.items, function (item) {
                for(var attr in item) {
                    if (searchMatch(item[attr], $scope.query))
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            });
            // take care of the sorting order
            if ($scope.sortingOrder !== '') {
                $scope.filteredItems = $filter('orderBy')($scope.filteredItems, $scope.sortingOrder, $scope.reverse);
            }
            $scope.currentPage = 0;
            // now group by pages
            $scope.groupToPages();
        };

        // calculate page in place
        $scope.groupToPages = function () {
            $scope.pagedItems = [];

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.filteredItems.length; i++) {
                if (i % $scope.itemsPerPage === 0) {
                    $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)] = [ $scope.filteredItems[i] ];
                } else {
                    $scope.pagedItems[Math.floor(i / $scope.itemsPerPage)].push($scope.filteredItems[i]);
                }
            }
        };

        $scope.range = function (start, end) {
            var ret = [];
            if (!end) {
                end = start;
                start = 0;
            }
            for (var i = start; i < end; i++) {
                ret.push(i);
            }
            return ret;
        };

        $scope.prevPage = function () {
            if ($scope.currentPage > 0) {
                $scope.currentPage--;
            }
        };

        $scope.nextPage = function () {
            if ($scope.currentPage < $scope.pagedItems.length - 1) {
                $scope.currentPage++;
            }
        };

        $scope.setPage = function () {
            $scope.currentPage = this.n;
        };

        // functions have been describe process the data for display
        $scope.search();

        // change sorting order
        $scope.sort_by = function(newSortingOrder) {
            if ($scope.sortingOrder == newSortingOrder)
                $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;

            $scope.sortingOrder = newSortingOrder;

            // icon setup
            $('th i').each(function(){
                // icon reset
                $(this).removeClass().addClass('icon-sort');
            });
            if ($scope.reverse)
                $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-up');
            else
                $('th.'+new_sorting_order+' i').removeClass().addClass('icon-chevron-down');
        };
    };
    ctrlRead.$inject = ['$scope', '$filter'];



HTML part
===========

    <html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.1.1/css/bootstrap.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/2.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.0/angular.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var sortingOrder = 'name';
        </script>
    </div>            
            <div ng-controller="ctrlRead">
                <div class="input-append">
                    <input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-change="search()" class="input-large search-query" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="id">Id&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('id')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                            <th class="name">Name&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('name')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                            <th class="description">Description&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('description')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                            <th class="field3">Field 3&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field3')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                            <th class="field4">Field 4&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field4')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                            <th class="field5">Field 5&nbsp;<a ng-click="sort_by('field5')"><i class="icon-sort"></i></a></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <td colspan="6">
                            <div class="pagination pull-right">
                                <ul>
                                    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == 0}">
                                        <a href ng-click="prevPage()">« Prev</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li ng-repeat="n in range(pagedItems.length)"
                                        ng-class="{active: n == currentPage}"
                                    ng-click="setPage()">
                                        <a href ng-bind="n + 1">1</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li ng-class="{disabled: currentPage == pagedItems.length - 1}">
                                        <a href ng-click="nextPage()">Next »</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tfoot>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
                            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.description}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.field3}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.field4}}</td>
                            <td>{{item.field5}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

In this samplecode they got all items once and perform action like paging.but my problem is if I have more than 15000 items in database then i couldn't get all record once as a performance point of view it will take time.so how can i achieve best approach of paging and sorting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do server side paging. Since you are using EF you can use linq to page data. Create a method like

```
PagedResult<User> GetPagedData(int pageNo, int pageSize) {
   int total=dbContext.Users.Count();
   List<Users> users = dbContext
          .Users
          .Skip(pageSize * pageNo)
         .Take(pageSize).ToList();
   return new PagedResult<User>() {
       Items=users,
       TotalRecords:total
   };
}
```

If you need sorting and filtering, you need to do it before you do `Skip` and `Take`.  Dynamic linq can help you here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library